# Invalid read of size 8 on valgrind c++

Tags: c++, oop, valgrind

Im getting this invalid read of size 8 and not sure how to go about this, im quite new to programming in general. Here are the codes that the problem is indicating.

```
 void Cargo::initialize(const char* desc, double weight)
    {       setDesc(desc);
            setWeight(weight);
    }
void Cargo::setDesc(const char* description)
    {
        if (strlen(description) <= MAX_DESC)
        {
            strncpy(m_description, description, MAX_DESC + 1);
        }
    }

    void Cargo::setWeight(double weight){   
       if (MIN_WEIGHT <= weight && weight <= MAX_WEIGHT)
            m_weight = weight;
        else
            m_weight = MIN_WEIGHT;
    }
```

```
double Cargo::getWeight() const
{
    return m_weight;
}
```

```
bool Train::swapCargo(Train &other)
{   
    bool isEmpty = false;
    if ((isValid() && other.isValid()))
    {

        Cargo temp;
        temp.initialize(pCargo->getDesc(), pCargo->getWeight());
        pCargo->initialize(other.pCargo->getDesc(), other.pCargo->getWeight());
        other.pCargo->initialize(temp.getDesc(), temp.getWeight());
        isEmpty = true;
        return isEmpty;
    }
    return isEmpty;
}
```

error from valgrind, i believe that maybe the problem is from the temp in swapCargo, but im not to sure. If i call  a class Cargo temp do i have to clear it , or only when i use "new " in it.:

```
==119155== Invalid read of size 8
==119155==    at 0x400B8C: sdds::Cargo::getWeight() const (Cargo.cpp:32)
==119155==    by 0x400F6E: sdds::Train::swapCargo(sdds::Train&) (Train.cpp:94)
==119155==    by 0x401A60: main (main_prof.cpp:131)
==119155==  Address 0x18 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==119155==
==119155==
==119155== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==119155==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x18
==119155==    at 0x400B8C: sdds::Cargo::getWeight() const (Cargo.cpp:32)
==119155==    by 0x400F6E: sdds::Train::swapCargo(sdds::Train&) (Train.cpp:94)
==119155==    by 0x401A60: main (main_prof.cpp:131)
==119155==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==119155==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==119155==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==119155==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==119155==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==119155==
==119155== HEAP SUMMARY:
==119155==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==119155==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 96 bytes allocated
==119155==
==119155== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==119155==
==119155== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==119155== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: What does the move constructor and move assignment operator look like in `Cargo`? Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: The error indicates that you are reading invalid memory.  This typically happens when walking off the end of an array or reading a dangling pointer.  I think it is likely that either `pCargo` or `other->pCargo` is dangling; `temp` is probably not a problem since it is on the stack.  Based on the error message the problem is on line 94 of `Train.cpp`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo , Thanks for helping me out , but what do you mean by move assignment operator the .h file?

Comment: @0x5453 You mean when it hits a nullbyte, i made sure to add +1 to the space. line 94 is this : ```temp.initialize(pCargo->getDesc(), pCargo->getWeight());```

Comment: `pCargo` is a null pointer. Why is it a pointer to begin with?

Comment: @PeterTran Ok, with the proper move semantics implemented in `Cargo`, swapping two `Cargo` objects would be as simple as: `std::swap(obj1, obj2);`. If you make a [mcve] we can perhaps help with that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo let me try to produce that here, i think i can do it with a few added func

Comment: @molbdnilo i set it to nullptr so that later in a diff function i would do pCargo = new Cargo[1] ?

Comment: Is pCargo some sort of global variable?

Comment: Thank you everyone who helped me , i manage to figure out the problem where i did not check if the train had any valid cargo thus creating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the Valgrind errors without seeing more of the code and the class definitions.

You are making your life harder by writing non-idiomatic C++ code. As a rule, if you do write idiomatic code and follow best practices then these types of problem rarely arise.

- Don't define your own swap function, use `std::swap` (as mentioned by @Ted Lyngmo in the comments)
- Don't write intitializer functions. Write constructors (perhaps delegating constructors if you want to reuse code and are using at least C++11).
- Don't use raw pointers (I'm guessing that pCargo is on such raw pointer).

Comment: I appreciate you mentioning that and ill remember what you have said. But in regards to all that, i was instructed to do so.